# Build Errors in Visual Studio 2019 inconsistently show up in Error List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I recently updated from Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition to Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Now, if I build my solution with errors, they will show up in the build output, but not all of them will appear in the error list.  It would appear only errors of open files will show up in the error list.  This is incredibly annoying.

I am not alone in this issue.  It has been reported many times on Microsoft's forums, but no one has a definitive solution.

I have tried a variety of solutions people suggested in those threads:

- I have ensured the filters are legitimate: Entire Solution, Errors enabled, Build + Intellisense.
- I have tried deleting the .vs folder and restarting Visual Studio.
- I just updated to the very latest Visual Studio 2019 version.  Supposedly there are many different versions of this error, happening in versions of Visual Studio all the way back to 2017.  Some supposedly have been fixed...?
- I have disabled parallel project loading.

I have experienced this before in other versions of Visual Studio with Razor pages.  To my knowledge, that's to be expected in Razor though.

The only other factor that I severely doubt impacts anything is that it's a Visual Studio project generated by Unity editor.  From what I've read, ASP.NET, Razor, Xamarin, and other frameworks have each had their own version of issue reported.  Perhaps Unity is afflicted by it too, but I don't see how or why.  I doubt Unity's auto-generated Visual Studio projects are *that* different from your standard library projects.

Comment: Have you clicked `Clear All Filters` in `Error List`?

Comment: Yes, but with no avail.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, have you reported this to Microsoft?

Comment: I have not, yet.  Given that several people have reported similar problems, and it came with Visual Studio 2019, I hoped it was something else.

Comment: Broken in v16.8.2 till at least v16.9.1 in Visual Studio 2019, and the accepted solution does not work. I'm having to copy the build output into Notepad++ and manually search for "error". We'll be back to pencil and paper soon if Microsoft keep "updating" Visual Studio...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have now installed Visual Studio 2019 on two separate machines, and it appears that "Full Solution Analysis" is disabled by default.

Simply check the checkbox in options and everything seems to work as it did previously:
[image: Enable Full Solution Analysis]

Comment: Thank you! I tried repeatedly to figure out how to fix this (the Visual Studio support forums were not helpful) and finally stumbled across this.

Comment: Unfortunately, even in the latest version (16.7.2), enabling Full solution analysis makes VS' overall performance nosedive (e.g. there's a very noticeable lag between typing and when the autocomplete/suggestions list appears or updates), and the responsiveness of VS' entire UI also suddenly turns sluggish whenever the Error List window is open with more than a handful of items.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in version 16.9.1 where the setting is called "background analysis scope" and set to "entire solution". This bug takes Visual Studio back to the stone age of doing manual builds to see if your code works :-(

Answer (score 3):

For those using Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.1 make sure your Error List window looks something like this:

[image: Error List Window]

The important part for me was selecting **Build + IntelliSense** (previously it was set to **Build Only** which explains why the error list would only refresh on build).

Comment: I've got the opposite problem. `Build + Intellisense` was showing me high-level errors only, but toggling to `Build Only` started showing me the actual build errors. They've broken something fundamental in the latest updates to VS2019...

Comment: @AlainD VS2019 has some really subtle weird bugs/issues (e.g. the scrollbar for the breakpoints window can't seem to size itself properly to allow scrolling the breakpoint list), I wish they would slow down the frequency of releases because a product as massive and as important as Visual Studio really needs to be rock solid.

Comment: I'm using VS 2019 16.11.5 and this is still an issue. Gah.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to switch off 'Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General->Show output window when build starts'. Even though the 'Output' window showed "0 succeeded, 1 failed" it would not switch back to the 'Error List' window even that the checkbox above 'Always show Error List if build finished with errors' should have moved it to 'Error List'. Clearly a bug in Visual Studio 2019 which was not present in Visual Studio 2017 (I just finished updating).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the fact that I was building under a Release profile. Once I chose Debug from the dropdown next to the Start Debugging button, it started showing my errors in the Error List after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was since the dependency dll was built for x86, but in the misbehaving project its reference was with processorArchitecture=MSIL